# graphics flowing in the text

Tags: graphics, luatex

I am trying to plot a graph G= on a slide and write some text under and over it but the graph is on its own page(and that page is much smaller then a normal one)

How can I get the graph flow in the text?

My document:

```
   % Drawing a graph using the PG 3.0 graphdrawing library
   % Author: Mark Wibrow
   \documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
   %%%<
   \usepackage{verbatim}
   %%%>

   \usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
   \usetikzlibrary{graphs}
   \usegdlibrary{trees}

   \begin{document}

   hekejehjejhjkhejkhhjke
   \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum      size=0.75cm}]
   \graph [tree layout, grow=down, fresh nodes, level distance=0.5in, sibling distance=0.5in]
    {
        A -> {
          B -> { A -> {C}, C -> {D} ,D },
          C -> { A, B -> {C  ,D} },
          D -> { C }
        }
    };

\end{tikzpicture}

ijklsjjkkjdkljkjl

\end{document}
```

compile with
   `lualatex filename.tex`

Comment: Replace the `standalone` class by a standard class (`article` for example). That implies not keeping the options `tikz` and `border=10pt`, of course.

Comment: \documentclass[]{article} or
\documentclass{article}

gives me 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.21 \usetikzlibrary
                  {graphdrawing}
?

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

followed by more errors!

Comment: You should load `tikz` as a separate package now: `\usepackage{tikz}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run with `LuaLaTeX` because of `graphdrawing` and change the `\documentclass` to some thing like `article` (as also suggested by fpast). The `standalone` was meant to be used for a single picture for example and not a running text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

Some text above.

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum      size=0.75cm}]
   \graph [tree layout, grow=down, fresh nodes, level distance=0.5in, sibling distance=0.5in]
    {
        A -> {
          B -> { A -> {C}, C -> {D} ,D },
          C -> { A, B -> {C  ,D} },
          D -> { C }
        }
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

Some other text below.

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]